# Praat script to extract one value from voice report

Tags: report, extract, voice, praat

I have a praat script in which a pitch object and a point process are created for an object. Then combining these 2 with my initial object returns me the voice report. I want to extract only the values of some fields and save them in a file, but I cannot find a way. Is it possible or should I just produce the report and then write a script in another programming language to extract them?

My script looks like that and I plan to put it in a for loop to run for multiple objects.

```
sound = selectObject: 1
pitch = To Pitch (cc)... 0.01 50 15 no 0.03 0.45 0.01 0.35 0.14 300
plus sound
pulses = To PointProcess (cc)
plus sound
plus pitch
voiceReport$ = Voice report... 0 0 50 300 1.3 1.6 0.03 0.45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `extractWord$()`, `extractLine$()`, and `extractNumber()` [string functions](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Formulas_5__String_functions.html).

Respectively, they extract from a string (in this case, `voiceReport$`) the word, line, or number that follows a specified string. You can use that specified string to identify the field in the voice report that you want.

Here's an example:

```
synth = Create SpeechSynthesizer: "English", "default"
sound = To Sound: "This is some text.", "no"
pitch = To Pitch (cc)... 0.01 50 15 no 0.03 0.45 0.01 0.35 0.14 300

selectObject: sound, pitch
pulses = To PointProcess (cc)

selectObject: sound, pulses, pitch
voiceReport$ = Voice report... 0 0 50 300 1.3 1.6 0.03 0.45

total_pulses = extractNumber(voiceReport$, "Number of pulses:")

writeInfoLine: "Found ", total_pulses, " pulses"

removeObject: synth, sound, pitch, pulses
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the answer helped, consider upvoting it in addition to marking it as accepted (which you already did).

Comment: Not enough reputation yet sorry.